# how to check if a word is a palindrome?

Tags: r

I would like to write a function which checks if a word is a palindrome. the return should tell me like

```
palindrome "love" is not a palindrome
```

the function should contain the word (not as a vector) as argument (I don't really understand what it means)

I tried

```
Palindrome <- function(character){
charsplit <- strsplit(as.character(character), "")
revchar <- rev(unlist(charsplit))
palinum <- as.numeric(paste(revchar, collapse=""))

character==palinum
}
```

but

```
Palindrome ("love")
```

returns

```
NA
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Um, you convert `paste(revchar, collapse="")` to numeric... what do you expect other than `NA`?

Comment: thanks! but the return now only says "THRUE" or "False", how can I make it to say "Hello is no palindrome"?

Comment: @user2373707 use `if-else` and `paste`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using `strsplit`:

```
is.palindrome <- function(word) {
    rawWord <- charToRaw(tolower(word)) ## converts to lower case
    sprintf("%s is %sa palindrome", word,
        c("not ", "")[identical(rawWord, rev(rawWord)) + 1])
}

> is.palindrome("otto")
[1] "otto is a palindrome"
> is.palindrome("love")
[1] "love is not a palindrome"
> is.palindrome("Otto")
[1] "Otto is a palindrome"
```

Comment: This approach will only with with ASCII characters: `is.palendrome("oço")`

Comment: facedictionary. Thanks @BenBolker.

Comment: @hadley, your example (and the counter-example `is.palindrome("oçro")`) work as expected on my setup. Not sure why there's a discrepancy (I'm in a latin-1 locale; the bit sequence of ç is symmetrical). I'll check into it more later.

Comment: @hadley, Thanks for pointing this out. The c-cedilla (ç) is in the Latin-1 supplement (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_characters_in_Unicode) and can be represented in 8 bits. However, anything beyond the Latin-1 supplement (for example a J circumflex) cannot be fully represented by 8 bits, and `is.palindrome()` will not work.

Answer (score 6):

```
is.palindrome <- function (word) {
  identical(word, paste(rev(strsplit(word, "")[[1]]), collapse=""))
}

is.palindrome("kayak")
[1] TRUE

is.palindrome("love")
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

This would work:

```
a = "blahalb"
identical(strsplit(a, "")[[1]], rev(strsplit(a, "")[[1]]))
#[1] TRUE

a = "love"
identical(strsplit(a, "")[[1]], rev(strsplit(a, "")[[1]]))
#[1] FALSE
```

Also, check out the `Kmisc` package for presumably faster results:

```
library(Kmisc)

a = c("blahalb", "love")
str_rev(a) == a
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

```
is_palindrome <- function(word){
  charsplit <- strsplit(word, "")[[1]]
  revchar <- rev(charsplit)

  all(charsplit==revchar)
}

is_palindrome("love")
is_palindrome("otto")
```

Comment: thank you! but how can I make it to return (Otto) as THRUE like (otto)?

Answer (score 2):

Can also be done using `substring()` and `rev()` functions :

```
is_palindrome <- function(x){

a <- substring(x,seq(1,nchar(x),1) , seq(1,nchar(x),1))
paste(rev(a),sep="",collapse="") == paste(a,sep="",collapse="")

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a C++ implementation:

```
sourceCpp('
bool isPalindrome(String x) {
  std::string y(x);
  int n = y.size();

  for(int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i) {
    if (y[i] != y[n - i - 1]) return false;
  } 

  return true; 
}
')
```

It doesn't work with non-ASCII strings either, but it's about 10x faster than the pure R solution:

```
library(microbenchmark)
options(digits = 3)

is.palindrome <- function (word) {
  identical(word, paste(rev(strsplit(word, "")[[1]]), collapse=""))
}

x <- paste(letters, rev(letters), collapse = "")
y <- paste("a", x)

microbenchmark(
  is.palindrome(x),
  isPalindrome(x),
  is.palindrome(y),
  isPalindrome(y)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#              expr   min    lq median    uq   max neval
#  is.palindrome(x) 24.62 25.99  27.14 28.29 36.38   100
#   isPalindrome(x)  2.38  2.68   2.82  3.58  4.03   100
#  is.palindrome(y) 24.68 26.44  27.78 28.46 80.94   100
#   isPalindrome(y)  2.33  2.67   3.41  3.64 33.60   100
```

Answer (score 2):

There is function in `stringi` package for that - `stri_reverse`

```
require(stringi)
stri_reverse("eye")
## [1] "eye"
stri_reverse("1234")
## [1] "4321"
```

Now palindrome function might as simple as that:

```
palindrome <- function(x) stri_reverse(x)==x
palindrome(c("love","1234321","eye","oço","ąłą"))
## [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```